# Trying to create a hashtable to get an arraylist from the text file - Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, token, hashtable

I am trying to create a hashtable to get an `ArrayList` from my text file read it and then count it into an another text file. I should tokenize each word and get the keys and values by counting them. So far I am still at the beginning and I don't get what is wrong with my code, it seems there is no error but it doesn't connect to the text and get the `ArrayList` or simply my code is wrong. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

This is the Map file

```
public class Map {
    public static String fileName= "C:Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt";

    private ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList <String>getList () {
        return this.arr;
    }

    private Hashtable<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

    public void load(String path) {
        try{
            FileReader f2 = new FileReader("C:Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f2);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                String[] words = line.split("\\s");
                for (int i=0;i<words.length; i++){
                    String word = words[i];
                    if (! word.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println(word);
                        arr.add(word);
                    }
                }
            }
            f2.close();
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
        }
        catch(IOException ex1)
        {
            Collections.sort(arr);
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            for (String counter: arr) {
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
            ex1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map m =new Map();
        m.load("C:Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\out.txt");
    }


    public Object get(String word) {
        return null;
    }

    public void put(String word, int i) {

    }


}
```

This is the Reduce file

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reduce {

    private Hashtable<String, Integer> map=new Hashtable< String, Integer>();

    public Hashtable < String, Integer> getHashTable () {
        return map;
    }

    public void setHashTable ( Hashtable < String, Integer> map){
        this.map =map;
    }

    public void findMin () {

    }

    public void findMax() {

    }

    public void sort (ArrayList<String> arr) throws IOException {
        Collections.sort(arr);
        Iterator it1 = arr.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            String word = it1.next().toString();
            System.out.println(word);

        }
    }
    //constructors
    public void reduce (ArrayList<String> words) {
        Iterator<String> it1 =words.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            String word=it1.next();
            System.out.println (word);
            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
            else {
                int count = map.get(word);
                map.put(word, count+1);
            }

            System.out.println( map.containsValue(word));


            }
        }


    }
```

Here is a part of workshop.txt. It is s basic simple text

"
                            Acknowledgements

I would like to thank Carl Fleischhauer and Prosser Gifford for the
opportunity to learn about areas of human activity unknown to me a scant
ten months ago, and the David and Lucile Packard Foundation for
supporting that opportunity.  The help given by others is acknowledged on
a separate page.

```
                                                      19 October 1992


           ***   ***   ***   ******   ***   ***   ***


                          INTRODUCTION
```

The Workshop on Electronic Texts (1) drew together representatives of
various projects and interest groups to compare ideas, beliefs,
experiences, and, in particular, methods of placing and presenting
historical textual materials in computerized form.  Most attendees gained
much in insight and outlook from the event.  But the assembly did not
form a new nation, or, to put it another way, the diversity of projects
and interests was too great to draw the representatives into a cohesive,
action-oriented body.(2)"

Comment: replace  C:Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt with C:\\Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt

Comment: Also, make it a practice to check if the file exists before reading it. if (file.exists()) {}

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn`t notice but it still doesn`t give an output

Comment: path is nowhere used. write to this file whatever is needed

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post (at least part of) file _workshop.txt_ ? By the way, which java version are you using?

Comment: sure, both done. Java 8 jdk-13.0.2

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a word frequency table. In other words you want to count how many times each distinct word occurs in the file _workshop.txt_. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, correct. but I should do this by using hashtable method

Comment: Most parts of your program do not make sense e.g. why you have used `System.out.println("An error occurred");` after `f2.close();`, why you are sorting `arr` inside `catch` block, why you have used raw `Iterator` instead of `Iterator<String>` , why you have used `Scanner` at one place while `BufferedReader` at another place for file reading, why you are reading the file multiple times etc. etc.

Comment: thank you, yes you are right. I tried multiple things to sort it out eventually. I will clear it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting word frequency in text can be accomplished using the java [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Here is my implementation, followed by explanatory notes.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WordFreq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("workshop.txt");
        Function<String, String> keyMapper = Function.identity();
        Function<String, Integer> valueMapper = (word) -> Integer.valueOf(1);
        BinaryOperator<Integer> mergeFunction = (a, b) -> Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + b.intValue());
        Supplier<Hashtable<String, Integer>> mapSupplier = () -> new Hashtable<>();
        try {
            Map<String, Integer> map = Files.lines(path)
                 .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\b")))
                 .filter(word -> word.matches("^\\w+$"))
                 .map(word -> word.toLowerCase())
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapSupplier));
            BiConsumer<String, Integer> action = (k, v) -> System.out.printf("%3d %s%n", v, k);
            map.forEach(action);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- Method `lines()` in class `java.nio.file.Files` creates a stream of the lines of text in the file. In this case the file is your *workshop.txt* file.
- For each line of the file that is read, I split it into words using method `split()` in class `java.lang.String` and convert the array returned by method `split()` into another stream.
- Actually each line of text is split at every word boundary so the array of words that method `split()` returns may contain strings that aren't really words. Therefore I filter the "words" in order to extract only real words.
- Then I convert each word to lower case so that my final map will be case-insensitive. In other words, the word *The* and the word *the* will be considered the same word.
- Finally I create a `Map` where the map key is a distinct word in the text of file `workshop.txt` and the map value is an `Integer` which is the number of occurrences of that word in the text.

Since you stipulated that the `Map` must be a `Hashtable`, I explicitly created a `Hashtable` to store the results of the `collect` operation on the stream.

The last part of the above code displays the contents of the `Hashtable`.

Comment: Thank you very much really! Even though it is a bit advanced for me I understand it thanks to your explanations. Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the first part, "Map" as below, now I have an alphabetically sorted array.
as follows..now I should count the tokenized key values.
"..
yet
yet
yet
yet
yet
yielded
you
young
zeal
zero.
zooming
..."

```
package com.company;


        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.util.Collections;

public class Map {

    public static String fileName= "C:\\Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt";



    private ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList <String>getList () {
        return this.arr;
    }

    private Hashtable<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

    public void load() {



        try{
            FileReader f2 = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\workshop.txt");

            Scanner s = new Scanner(f2);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                String[] words = line.split("\\s");
                for (int i=0;i<words.length; i++){
                    String word = words[i];
                    if (! word.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println(word);
                        arr.add(word);
                    }
                }
            }
            f2.close();
            System.out.println();


    }
            catch(IOException ex1){
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");
             ex1.printStackTrace(); }
        {
            Collections.sort(arr);
            System.out.println("Sorted.");
            for (String counter: arr) {
                System.out.println(counter);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map m =new Map();
        m.load();
    }
}
```

The second part which is doing the reducing is:

```
package com.company;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reduce {

    private Hashtable<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();


    public Hashtable<String, Integer> getHashTable() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setHashTable(Hashtable<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }


    //constructors
    public void reduce (ArrayList<String> arr) {
        Iterator<String> it1 = arr.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            String word = it1.next();
            System.out.println(word);
            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                int a = (int) map.get(word);
                a++;
                map.put(word, a);
            } else {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
    }



    public void write () {

        try {
            FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\ruken\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\output.txt");
            Iterator<String> it1 = map.keySet().iterator();
            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                String word = it1.next().toString();
                f1.write(word + "" + ":" + "" + map.get(word) + "\n" );
            }
            f1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Map m =new Map();
        m.load();
        Reduce r = new Reduce ();
        ArrayList<String> arr=  m.getList();
        r.reduce(arr);
        r.write();
    }
}
```